# How to use AverageIf filtering every 2 columns of 2 specific rows?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm setting up a personal budget sheet and I want to know how to count a cell to average only if the respective cell in the same column is less than or equal to today's date.

The cells I want to average up appear every 2 columns in the sheet (C14, E14, G14), but the cells I want to put in my criteria_range parameter is merged (B1+C1, D1+E1, F1+G1).

[image]

I have the following formula:

```
=averageif(
    filter(C14:Y14, mod((column(C14:Y14)+1), 2)=0),
    "<="&today(),
    filter(A1:Y1, mod((column(A1:Y1)+1), 2))
 )
```

Following the parameter specifications:

```
AVERAGEIF(criteria_range, criterion, [average_range])
```

I've pasted the 2 individual filter functions on its own row and they return what I expected:

[image]

However, the main formula returns #N/A as the value. Any suggestions is appreciated thanks!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=average(query(transpose({filter(B1:I1, mod((column(B1:I1)+1), 2)>0);filter(B4:I4, mod((COLUMN(B4:I4)+1), 2)=0)}),"Select Col2 where Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(TODAY()),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))
```

- Replace the ranges for the dates and the total.

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

---

## **What it does?**

**1. Concatenate and transpose date row and total row using `transpose({row1;row2})` syntax**

[image]

**2. Use [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) to get the rows with <= date specified.**

Reference: [Filtering with dates in the QUERY function](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/)

> In this case, I changed the date to <= 3/1/2020.

[image]

**3. Get the average.**

[image]

---

The reason why you are encountering issues using [AVERAGEIF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529) is because the third parameter of this function requires a "range", wherein the result of a [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) is an array.

Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/17437868?hl=en

Comment: Where did Col1 and Col2's name come from? is it hardcoded? I'm getting a parsing error with the query

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I guess this makes sense... Although there are many steps, if this is the most straightforward way to get the results I need, then it's good.